# How to wrap an `apply-template` element with a `div` element using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to wrap a repeating `system-folder` element with a `div` tag. I could have two to three `system-folder` elements all wrapped with `div`.

A `system-page` element can be previous or following siblings.

Any idea on what I need to change to implement this?  Do I need to make use of preceding siblings and make 3 apply template calls?

**XML**

```
<system-index-block current-time="1370982198860" name="index-block" type="folder">

  <system-page id="3499046a0a1e023a19a05c9328c6e360">
    <name>calendar</name>
    <title>College Catalog</title>
    <display-name>Enter a display name (For Navigation)</display-name>
    <path>/web/catalog/calendar</path>
  </system-page>

  <system-folder id="348ce18d0a1e023a19a05c93941a001d">
    <name>general</name>
    <display-name>General Information</display-name>
    <path>/web/catalog/general</path>
    <system-page id="348d29520a1e023a19a05c9362978f0d">
      <name>history</name>
      <title>History of the College</title>
      <display-name>Enter a display name (For Navigation)</display-name>
      <path>/web/catalog/general/history</path>
    </system-page>
  </system-folder>

  <system-folder id="348ce18d0a1e023a19a05c93941a001d">
    <name>general</name>
    <display-name>General Information</display-name>
    <path>/web/catalog/general</path>
    <system-page id="348d29520a1e023a19a05c9362978f0d">
      <name>history</name>
      <title>History of the College</title>
      <display-name>Enter a display name (For Navigation)</display-name>
      <path>/web/catalog/general/history</path>
    </system-page>
  </system-folder>

  <system-page current="true" id="341f70a80a1e023a19a05c93a172e372">
    <name>index</name>
    <title>College Catalog</title>
    <display-name>Enter a display name (For Navigation)</display-name>
    <path>/web/catalog/index</path>
  </system-page>

</system-index-block>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="system-page">

    <xsl:variable name="x">
      <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:if test="@current='true'">
          <xsl:attribute name="class">current-nav-link</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="path"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="parent::system-index-block">
        <div class="nav-entry-link">
          <xsl:copy-of select="$x" />
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <li>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$x" />
        </li>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="system-folder">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="display-name" /></h2>
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="system-page">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<div class="nav-entry-link">
  <a href="/web/catalog/calendar">College Catalog</a>
</div>

<h2>General Information</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/web/catalog/general/history">History of the College</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/web/catalog/general/payment">test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/web/catalog/general/governance">Governance</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<h2>General Information</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/web/catalog/general/history">History of the College</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/web/catalog/general/payment">test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/web/catalog/general/governance">Governance</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="nav-entry-link">
  <a class="current-nav-link" href="/web/catalog/index">College Catalog</a>
</div>
```

I would like to get all the `h2` and `ul` elements wrapped like this:

```
<div class="nav-entry-link">
  <a href="/web/catalog/calendar">College Catalog</a>
</div>
    <div class="accordion">
      <h2>test</h2>
      <ul>test</ul>
      <h2>test</h2>
      <ul>test</ul>
    </div>
<div class="nav-entry-link">
  <a href="/web/catalog/calendar">College Catalog</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Are you saying that you want all sequences of top-level `system-folder` sequence of `h2` and `ul` elements contained within a `<div class="nav-entry-link">` element? Are `system-folder` and `system-page` elements interspersed in any order, and do you want to keep that order? What about sequences of `system-page` elements? Do you want those wrapped in separate `div` elements as well, as you show in your current XML output?

Comment: the system-folder element are siblings of system-page. The system folders will be wrapped in just 1 div for an accordion. Sytem pages that are not children of system-folder should have seaprate divs.

Comment: The order will probably stay pretty consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

Add a template which ignores system-folder which have direct preceding-sibling system-folder.

```
<xsl:template match="system-folder[preceding-sibling::*[1][name() = 'system-folder']]" />
```

And a template which generate a dif

```
<xsl:template match="system-folder">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="following" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

And have a recursive call to following siblings.
Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="system-page">

        <xsl:variable name="x">
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:if test="@current='true'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">current-nav-link</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="path"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="parent::system-index-block">
                <div class="nav-entry-link">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$x" />
                </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <li>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$x" />
                </li>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="system-folder[preceding-sibling::*[1][name() = 'system-folder']]" />
    <xsl:template match="system-folder">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="following" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="system-folder" mode="following">

        <h2>
            <xsl:value-of select="display-name" />
        </h2>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="system-page">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][name() = 'system-folder']" mode="following" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<div class="nav-entry-link">
    <a href="/web/catalog/calendar">College Catalog</a>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>General Information</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/web/catalog/general/history">History of the College</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>General Information</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/web/catalog/general/history">History of the College</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div class="nav-entry-link">
    <a class="current-nav-link" href="/web/catalog/index">College Catalog</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that did it! Thank you. I'm going to go through the code now. What does this mean: preceding-sibling::*[1][name() = 'system-folder']]

Comment: `preceding-sibling::*` looks for all elements before the current belonging to the same parent. `[1]` take from this elmeents the first one (the element just before the current). `[name() = 'system-folder']` test if this element is an system-folder.

Comment: So as the XSLT processor is proccessing apply-templates, node(), it lands on the first system-folder, what happens from there?

Comment: It will generate the wonted div and apply-templates for this system-folder again, but with mode=follwing. Which generate the `<h2>` etc. and calls recursively the same template (for direct following) while there are direct following "system-folder"

Comment: thanks, i'm not familiar with mode=folllowing, so guess i have some reading to do.

Comment: so i understand what happens when u hit following-sibling::*[1][name() = 'system-folder'],  this is getting all of next siblings.  i'm still confused though on the role of preceding-siblings... thanks again!